# google-drive-sdk : call google-drive-sdk

Tags: google-drive-api

I am new using google scripts and drive-sdk.

I'd like to call the copy functionality of drive-sdk. When I try it, I get a message that says I need authentication.

Where can I find an example of how can I authenticate from a google script to authenticate de drive-sdk?

Thanks in advance.

Biagio

Comment: you need to use OAuth 2.0 to authenticate with Google, which uses access token mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Google's Drive SDK docs regarding [authentication](https://developers.google.com/drive/about-auth).

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-php is a good example in PHP. other languages they have quickstart examples for: Java, Python, .NET, Ruby, Javascript, Go, and Objective-C/iOS

Answer (score 0):

First, view Google's information on [authorising with the Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth).

Then, choose which language you wish to use, I would reccomend JavaScript (or Node.js) if you want to play around or are making a web app.

If you wish, you can view a [simplified explanation of the OAuth2.0 flow](https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/).

To clarify, the basic steps you can use to get going in JavaScript (as an example) are:

1. View [this official Google getting started page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js)
2. [Set up the Drive API in the Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=drive&pli=1)
3. Copy the code from the getting started page
4. Ensure you place your ClientID from the Google Developer console into the copied code
5. Install Python if you haven't already (version 2 or 3)
6. Start the web server using Python (`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` for version 2) and load 'http://localhost:8000/quickstart.html' into your web browser